# describe in rspec. When to use quotes?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Sometimes I see rspecs that look like this:

```
describe Contact do
...
end
```

and sometimes I see them like this:

```
describe 'Contact' do
...
end
```

What's the difference? And more generically, where can I find the docs for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific class to describe, then you should use constant form. If you do, you will have `described_class` helper method that returns that class. Maybe come in handy in specs.

```
describe Contact do
  puts described_class # >> Contact
end

describe "Contact" do
  puts described_class # >> nil
end
```

Also, as @Santosh noted, constant form guards you from typos in class names. Say, you renamed a model, but forgot to update the specs. You'll get an error when running specs.

If this spec file is not focused on one class and is, for example, testing integration of several things, then you, naturally, don't use a constant. Because you don't have a definite one.

```
describe "user registration process" do
  # integration specs
end
```

Answer (score 1):

describe is a `method` which takes an `argument` and a `block`

Look at it this way

```
 describe('Contact', {})
```

If `Contact` is a `class`, you can pass it as a `parameter` like you do when you write your model specs.

```
describe(Contact, {}) # If Contact class doesn't exist, you will get an error
```